How to use AFL to test functions with struct parameters?
I am new to fuzz. Due to the supervisor's task, I am testing a series of small functions whose parameters are structures, such as
struct Node{
    int a;
    float b;
}
void foo(Node node){...}

And he asked me to try using AFL .But I found that AFL can only mutate the content of an input file and use it for testing, that is, the program can only get a character array. So how can I use AFL to generate these structure data?
I must use AFL, so please do not mention other tools such as AFL++.
I think the only way is to split this character array in some way and assign the values ​​of each sub-array to each structure variable, but this will make it more random.


Write code that saves your structure type variable to a file, something like this:
 Node new_node;    
 new_node.a = realistic_value_for_a;              
 //Use realistic values for initializing the fields of your object.    
 new_node.b = realistic_value_for_b;    

 FILE* pFile = fopen( "your_file_name", "wb" );    
 fwrite( &new_node, sizeof(new_node), 1, pFile );    
 fclose( pFile );

This is an example without any error checks etc.

Modify your test to read the object from the file and pass it to the func, for example:
 Node new_node;

 FILE* pFile = fopen( "your_file_name", "rb" );

 fread( &new_node, sizeof(new_node), 1, pFile );

 fclose( pFile );

 foo(new_node);


Use the file written in step 1 as seed in AFL.



Thank you! I didn't even know that fread and fwrite could read and write structures before.
